# React component react-xarrows

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react-xarrows react component and it works good but it shows aero only if it pre defined is it possiable to create that areo dynamically as user wants
code is...

```js
import React from 'react';
import Xarrow, {useXarrow, Xwrapper} from 'react-xarrows';
import Draggable from 'react-draggable';

const boxStyle = {border: 'grey solid 2px', borderRadius: '10px', padding: '5px'};

const DraggableBox = ({id}) => {
    const updateXarrow = useXarrow();
    return (
        <Draggable onDrag={updateXarrow} onStop={updateXarrow}>
            <div id={id} style={boxStyle}>
                {id}
            </div>
        </Draggable>
    );
};

export function V2Example() {
    return (
        <div style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-evenly', width: '100%'}}>
            <Xwrapper>
                <DraggableBox id={'elem1'}/>
                <DraggableBox id={'elem2'}/>
                <Xarrow start={'elem1'} end="elem2"/>
            </Xwrapper>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to create arrows dynamically using the `react-xarrows` library. You can achieve this by maintaining a state for the arrows in your component and updating it based on user interactions.

You can implement it using an react hook (useState), here's an example code to implement arrows dynamically.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Xarrow, { useXarrow, Xwrapper } from 'react-xarrows';
import Draggable from 'react-draggable';
  
export function V2Example() {
    const [arrows, setArrows] = useState([]);

    const addArrow = (start, end) => {
        setArrows([...arrows, {start, end}]);
    };

    return (
        <div style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-evenly', width: '100%'}}>
            <Xwrapper>
                <DraggableBox id={'elem1'}/>
                <DraggableBox id={'elem2'}/>
                {arrows.map((arrow, index) => (
                    <Xarrow key={index} start={arrow.start} end={arrow.end}/>
                ))}
            </Xwrapper>
            <button onClick={() => addArrow('elem1', 'elem2')}>Add Arrow</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

The `addArrow` function is used to add a new arrow to the state when the button is clicked. You can modify this function to add arrows based on different user interactions.Please note that you need to ensure the elements you’re referencing in your arrows `(start and end)` exist in the DOM

Comment: Give me brief about your query.

Comment: Can I select specific arrow to delete that arrow?